Can someone re-enter the USA on a tourist visa after 8 months outside of the country when they stayed earlier in the USA for 12 months?
My divorced parent came to visit us in the USA last year on tourist visas and then towards the end of their 6 months stay we extended their stay for another 6 months officially by applying for an extension.
I know that there are no defined official rules on how soon someone can re-enter on a tourist visa, but the general unofficial guidance says to stay out of the country an amount of time at least equal to the time spent in the USA. Now due to loneliness and other issues that affect them, we want them to visit us sooner at around 8 months, rather than staying out of the country for a year. Does anyone know if this will be acceptable, risky or will they be denied entry for coming sooner?

No one can really give you any meaningful insight. This is a decision that will fall squarely on how convinced the border agent is regarding immigrant intent (or lack thereof). Anything anyone says will be pure opinion or speculation.

Convincing the border agent regarding intent will depend on factors such as their citizenship and ability to demonstrate strong ties to their country of residence (house, job, other family etc), proposed length of stay. Be prepared to explain how they can spend 12 months away from home and then return for (possibly) another lengthy visit after only 8 months back home. Not a typical visit pattern for the average tourist. Do they actually have B1/B2 visas, or are they VWP/ESTA?

What it is the purpose of the visit of someone? You do not need to answer us, but you should think immigration officer will have such question (and officers will care about facts, not what the person tell him). Personally: I think it is risky, and every new entry it will be riskier.

Did your parents lodge a US tax return, listing all global income?  If they were in the US for 12 months they have a legal requirement to do this.
